# Finagle and load balancing

Tags: finagle, twitter-finagle

I have seen in many places that Finagle has service discovery and load balancing capabilities, but I cannot find any reference to actual detailed implementation.

How does Finagle client get the address of the Service Discovery?

How is such a service discovery implemented?

The documentation seems incomplete...

Thanks!